# How to use POST of servicestack swift client?

Tags: swift, servicestack

Here is my C# servicestack code

```
[Route("/timeline/days/createmodify")]
public class CreateModifyTimelineDaysRequest:IReturn<bool>
{
    public int guide_id { get; set; }
    public List<TimeLineDayModel> Days { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I have in Swift

```
var error:NSError?
let req:CreateModifyTimelineDaysRequest = CreateModifyTimelineDaysRequest()
req.guide_id = self.guide_id
req.days = self.theguide2.days

var client = JsonServiceClient(baseUrl: "http://localhost/panograph_api")
var response = client.post(req, error: &error)
```

But the last line in swift has a compilation error, Can't invoke post with an argument list of type (CreateModifyTimelineDaysRequest, error:inout NSError?)

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DTO's should either return ideally Response DTO's otherwise can return reference types like `string`, it should never return Value Types like `bool`.

Comment: Can we return List<T> ?

Comment: @shawhu Normally yes, but [not for Swift which doesn't allow extending generic arrays](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swift-Add-ServiceStack-Reference#ireturn-not-added-for-array-responses). You'll need to wrap it in a Response DTO.

Comment: I've tried to return List<TimeLineDayModel> but failed too. I tried to return String, that is working. So, I guess we can only return either T or any reference types but not List<T>. Right?

Comment: @shawhu Right, that's what I said in my comment wasn't supported in Swift. May be able to in future after Swift 2.0's released if it added support for extending generic arrays.